# Is this true? If $X$ has no isolated points and $D$ is dense, then every non-empty open of $X$ intersects $D$ infinitely many times?

Tags: general-topology

> **Proposition.** Let $X$ denote a topological space and $D$ denote a dense subset thereof. Then for all open $U \subseteq X$, either $U$ is empty, or $|U \cap D| \geq 1.$

However, in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, we can say a lot more:

> **Proposition.** Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $X$ has the following property: if $D$ is a dense subset of $X$, then for all open $U \subseteq X$, either $U$ is empty, or $|U \cap D| \geq \aleph_0$.

I'm a little confused about which spaces $X$ have this property. Clearly, if $X$ has an isolated point, then it can't have the property of interest. My question is whether the converse holds, and if not, what can we say?

> **Question.** Is it true that if $X$ has no isolated points, then if $D$ is a dense subset of $X$, then for all open $U \subseteq X$, either $U$ is empty, or $|U \cap D| \geq \aleph_0$?
>
> If not, what can we say?

Comment: Do you assume some separation properties on $X$? Otherwise, take a space with a dense singleton and no isolated points (e.g. the topology $\{(-n,n)\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ on $\Bbb R$, where $\{0\}$ is dense, but there are no isolated points).

Comment: @AsafKaragila, please assume whatever separation properties you like! Weird, strange spaces... just, yuk :) That's a nice counterexample btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a topological space $X$, the following are equivalent:

1. $\{x\}$ is nowhere dense for every $x \in X$.
2. Every finite subset of $X$ is nowhere dense.
3. $D \cap U$ is infinite for every dense $D \subset X$ and every nonempty open $U \subset X$.

*Proof:*

$[1 \implies 2]$: A finite union of nowhere dense sets is still nowhere dense.

$[2 \implies 3]$: $D \cap U$ is dense in $U$. Therefore $D \cap U$ is infinite.

$[3 \implies 1]$: $\{x\} \cup (X\setminus \overline{\{x\}})$ is dense in $X$ and its intersection with $\operatorname{int} \overline{\{x\}}$ is a subset of $\{x\}$. Therefore
$\operatorname{int} \overline{\{x\}} =  \emptyset$. $\square$

In a T1 space, a singleton is nowhere dense unless it is open, so a T1
space without isolated points satifies 1-3.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $X$ is Hausdorff, then the answer is positive. Suppose that $D$ is dense and $U$ is open, choose some $x,y\in U$ and find some $V,V'\subseteq U$ which are disjoint, with $x\in V$ and $y\in V'$.

Then by density $V\cap D$ and $V'\cap D$ are both non-empty. And therefore $U\cap D$ contains at least two points. By induction this shows that the intersection of $D$ and $U$ contains infinitely many points.

(I think that almost the same argument should also work for $T_1$ spaces, but I'm not entirely sure about $T_0$ spaces.)

---

If you don't require any separation, then taking $\Bbb R$ with the topology $\{(-n,n)\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{\Bbb R\}$ is a counterexample with $D=\{0\}$ as your dense set.

Comment: Fwiw, I got it to work for $T_1$ spaces.

Comment: If we endow $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology having as a sub-basis the sets $(-r,0]$ and $[0,r)$, for all $r>0$, then this is also a counterexample, with $D = \{0\}$, isn't it? And it is $T_0$.

Comment: @amrsa: Yes, it seems like a good counterexample. Thus we consolidated that $T_1$ is needed, but $T_0$ is not enough.

Comment: @amrsa: If $(-1,0]$ and $[0, 1)$ are open, then $0$ is an isolated point.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen Yes, of course! I forgot that detail. Maybe if we consider all open intervals (in the usual topology) containing $0$? Then $0$ is no longer an isolated point; it seems to me it is still a $T_0$ space, for the same reason, and taking $D=\{0\}$ we still have a counterexample.

Comment: @amrsa: yes, that works.